# Strange results with OpenCV camera calibration

Tags: python, opencv

I'm calibrating my GoPro following the OpenCV [tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html). To calibrate, I have a bunch of pictures with a chessboard in different locations. I then plot the 3D axis on top of the chessboard and everything looks fine, the calibration seems good:

[image: Axis successfully plotted]

Then I want to see the undistorted version of the image without cropping anything and I get this:

[image]

Which clearly doesn't make any sense. I have tried to do the same thing with another set of calibration images and it worked:

[image]

I don't understand why it didn't work with the first set of pictures. Any ideas?

Here's the relevant code:

```
# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((9*6,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:9,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

files = os.listdir('frames')
for fname in files:
    g = re.match('frame(\d+).png',fname)
    n = g.groups()[0]
    if n not in numbers:
        os.remove('frames/%s'%fname)
        continue
    img = cv2.imread('frames/%s'%fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (9,6),None)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (9,6), corners2,ret)
        objpoints.append(objp)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)
        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

ret, K, D, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
# K: intrinsic matrix - camera matrix
# D: Distortion coefficients 

#Compute reconstruction error
mean_error = 0
for i in xrange(len(objpoints)):
    imgpoints2, _ = cv2.projectPoints(objpoints[i], rvecs[i], tvecs[i], K, D)
    error = cv2.norm(imgpoints[i],imgpoints2, cv2.NORM_L2)/len(imgpoints2)
    mean_error += error

print "total error: ", mean_error/len(objpoints)

ret, rvec, tvec = cv2.solvePnP(objp, corners2, K, D)

# project 3D points to image plane Using openCV
imgpts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis, rvec, tvec, K, D)
img = draw(img,corners2,imgpts)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff

f = file('camera.pkl','wb')
cPickle.dump((K,D,rvec,tvec),f)
f.close()


#get the Undistorted image
h,  w = img.shape[:2]
newcameraK, roi=cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(K,D,(w,h),1,(w,h))

dst = cv2.undistort(img, K, D, None, newcameraK)

plt.figure()
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(dst,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

Comment: What did the first set of calibration images look like (all of them)?

Comment: from my experience, calibrateCamera function optimizes within the image area where samples are given, so try to place the calibration pattern to cover as much of the image as possible!

Comment: @DanMašek my calibration images all look good (the grid was at the right place). I had lot's of images that were in very similar places (redundant) I deleted a few and the result got much better. Don't know the reason though.. redundant images shouldn't matter right?

Comment: Redundant images matter "a little"; the effectively make those images (and therefore, the location of the checkerboard pattern in those images) more important.  Micka's point is also important; making sure that the calibration grid fills as much of the image as possible is important, or at least have some pictures of the checkerboard where it is near the boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Micka's point is important; making sure that the calibration grid fills as much of the image as possible is important, or at least have some pictures of the checkerboard where it is near the boundaries.

This issue is that distortion is small near the center and large at the boundaries. A large distortion therefore doesn't affect the center of the image very much.  Equivalently, a small error in estimating the distortion from the center of the image leads to a perhaps very wrong overall estimate of the distortion.

Redundant images matter "a little"; it is effectively making those images (and therefore, the location of the checkerboard pattern in those images) more important.

Answer (score 1):

i also observed the same effect but much stranger:

When i use getOptimalTransformationMatrix my resulting images also have those strong circular distortion effect like above. Also changing the alpha does not solve it. BUT: When i use same distortion/calibration results WITHOUT getOptimalTransformationMatrix (so i use same fx/fy/cx/cy as on camera calibration result) i get a very good result in undistortion.... very strange....

could it be that in some situations the getOptimalTransformationMatrix function is buggy? My calibration (images etc) look very good, points are on edges too